# How to resolve java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol:?

Tags: java, html, swing, url, jeditorpane

Code:

```
public SelectedMap() {
    initComponents();
    editorMap_pn.setEditable(false);
    try {
        editorMap_pn.setPage("<html><body>Hello</body></html>");
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(SelectedMap.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Tracker.UI.SelectedMap <init>
SEVERE: null
java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: <html><body>Hello</body></html>
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:583)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:480)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:429)
    at javax.swing.JEditorPane.setPage(JEditorPane.java:882)
    at Tracker.UI.SelectedMap.<init>(SelectedMap.java:33)
```

I want to show HTML page in Java application but not a URL.
I want to input HTML code as an input to setter and show the web output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation for `JEditorPane.setPage(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JEditorPane.html#setPage-java.lang.String-) tells us:

> Sets the current **`URL`** being displayed.

So:

```
editorMap_pn.setPage("<html><body>Hello</body></html>");
```

Should be:

```
editorMap_pn.setText("<html><body>Hello</body></html>");
```

Note that you might also need to set a content type and non-editable.